How do we know that the integral of an unknown T-periodic function minus its average is itself T-periodic?
I need to find $P(t)$ and $B$ in $\mathbf{\Phi}(t) = P(t)e^{Bt}$ (Floquet) for the differential equation
$\dot{x} = f(t)x$. $f(t)$ is not further specified, but is said to be T-periodic. That is, there exists some T such that $f(t) = f(t+T)$ for all t.
I found the simple general solution to this ODE: $x(t) = x_0 e^{\int_0^{t}f(t)dt}$. And since this is a scalar problem, my fundamental matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}$ is simply $x(t)$, which I want to represent as the multiplication of $P(t)$ (which is T-periodic) and $e^{Bt}$ where B is a constant.
Thus, I need to rewrite $x(t)$ to a form that is separable in the way I described. Rewritten, as stated as a solution is
$$x(t) = x_0 e^{\int_0^{t}(f(\tau)-f_{avg})d\tau + f_{avg}t}$$ where $$f_{avg} = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^{T}f(\tau)d\tau.$$
I see that this form is equivalent to the other form I produced, but my question is, how do we know that $ \int_{0}^{t} (f(\tau) - f_{avg}) d\tau$ is (also) T-periodic, such that in the exponent it can serve as the $T$-periodic function $P(t)$ that I am looking for.
I've considered a Fourier expansion, but since $f(t)$ is a general function of which I only know that it is T-periodic, I don't know how to proceed.
I've gotten up to:
$f(t) \approx \frac{a_0}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(nt) + b_n \sin(nt)$ with
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}f(t)\,dt, $$
$$a_n = \frac{2}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}f(t)\cos(2nt\pi/T)\,dt,$$
$$b_n = \frac{2}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}f(t)\sin(2nt\pi/T)\,dt$$

What did you try?

What does it mean for a function to be $T$-periodic?  Have you applied that definition to this problem?

Don't overcomplicate it: just try to show directly that $F(t+T) = F(t)$, if we denote $F$ teh function of interest.

@BrunoB Right. So I can see how if one subtracts the average this essentially 'zero's out' the function as it is integrated over one period, meaning that after exactly one period the integral goes to zero, thereby being T-periodic? It makes sense in my head now, not sure yet how that would look on paper. Thank you!
